# Copying assets directory from source to build directory in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, assets

I am trying to write a game for practice in C++. I am using CMake for this, and my project gets built in a separate build directory automatically by my IDE. However, my `assets` folder is *not* being copied over to the new directory.

Currently, I am attempting to resolve this with the following:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND cp -r ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/assets ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
    )
```

However, this seems to have absolutely no effect on the outcome and the assets directory is still *not* present in my build directory.

How can I actually make it copy this asset directory to my build location? Is there a smarter way to point my program to my assets location (perhaps one that will also work with assets in /usr/share?)

Answer (score 21):

After quite a while of more searching, I managed to find the `file(COPY {files} DESTINATION {directory})` command:

```
file(COPY assets DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
```

Comment: Thanks! I had the same issue and this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Note that this will **not** update the target if you modify files. You should use `add_custom_target` to create the assets target, and `add_dependencies` to make the program depend on it.

Answer (score 19):

Two ways I've found, both ensuring that it copies on target build and stays up to date even if the target doesn't need to re-build.

---

The first uses the CMake command line tool `copy_directory`. It's unclear from the documentation whether this copy always happens, regardless if files in the `assets` directory were updated or not, or if it only copies when the asset files don't exist or an asset file was updated:

```
add_custom_target(copy_assets
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/assets ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/assets
)
add_dependencies(mytarget copy_assets)
```

---

The second requires a small additional CMake script file, but it allows us to use the `file(COPY ...)` CMake comamnd, which states in the documentation that "copying preserves input file timestamps, and optimizes out a file if it exists at the destination with the same timestamp."

First, create the CMake script file `copy-assets.cmake` in the same directory as your `CMakeLists.txt`, with the contents being (similar to Ethan McTague's answer)

```
file(COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/assets DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

And then in your `CMakeLists.txt`, add the following:

```
add_custom_target(copy_assets
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/copy-assets.cmake
)
add_dependencies(mytarget copy_assets)
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution and thanks for including the second method, I might use it soon!

Comment: If you don't care if the assets get copied before or after `mytarget`, you can remove the line: `add_dependencies(mytarget copy_assets)` and add `ALL` to the custom_target, like so: `add_custom_target(copy_assets ALL`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution above using `add_custom_target` is suitable for most cases, but has a few problems.

- Does not support dependent generator expressions (e.g. $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:tgt>)
- Re-copies every build (slow for numerous/large files)
- Is not particularly readable, especially for copying from multiple locations

Instead, I've been using [file GENERATE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#generate:)

```
set(ASSETS
    assetfile
    ...)
foreach(ASSET ${ASSETS})
    file(GENERATE OUTPUT ${ASSET} INPUT ${ASSET})
endforeach()
```

Note I haven't needed generator expressions yet, but it looks like the latest version of CMake (3.19) adds generator expression support to this function.

Comment: Unfortunately this command will treat all your files as text files, and potentially do EOL conversions and other stuff you don't want done to your binary assets such images, models, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I do with vulkan shaders. Simply replace the compilation step with a copy command:

```
macro(add_shaders)
    cmake_parse_arguments("MY" "TARGET" "SOURCES" ${ARGN})

    foreach(src ${MY_SOURCES})
        set(OUTF "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/shaders/${src}.spv")
        get_filename_component(PARENT_DIR "${OUTF}" DIRECTORY)
        add_custom_command(
            OUTPUT "${OUTF}"
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory "${PARENT_DIR}"
            COMMAND "${Vulkan_GLSLC_EXECUTABLE}" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${src}" -o "${OUTF}"
            DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${src}"
            VERBATIM
        )
        # src in order to get listed in the IDE, OUTF to declare the build relationship
        target_sources("${MY_TARGET}" PRIVATE "${src}" "${OUTF}")
    endforeach()
endmacro()
```

```
add_shaders(TARGET my_target SOURCES asset1 asset2 asset3 ...)
```

You'll have to specify each asset on its own (or loop over a list). Including wildcards into a build is a bad idea [tm]. This will also only copy/process stuff if it has changed.